# Application deploy in IIS

Tags: ssl, https, iis-7, iis-8

web Application deployed in IIS.Add port 443 for HTTPS.
And also create new SSL certificate for HTTPS.

finally,login in my application(its done).Once I refresh the browser.IIS 443 (Https)port automatically removed in IIS and application can't reached

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't set the url rewrite to redirect from http to https.

I suggest you could install the [url rewrite module](https://www.cyotek.com/blog/installing-the-url-rewrite-module-into-internet-information-services) and add below url rewrite in the web.config to redirect all the request from http to https:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to http" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" negate="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Details, you could refer to below article:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dawiese/2016/06/07/redirect-from-http-to-https-using-the-iis-url-rewrite-module/